# three.js sphere not spinning on mobile and works really slow on destop

Tags: three.js

Im still learning three.js, and im having trouble figuring out why this sphere doesnt work on mobile, 
http://wander.ventures/sphere.html

but this other cube i have runs smoothly, and without a problem
http://wander.ventures/test/sphere.html

is it the skin?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the sphere scene. For one you have specified too many faces `SphereGeometry(200, 200, 200)`. The first value is the radius while the second and third are the widthSegments and heightSegments. Those arguments create the faces of the sphere. Try something like 20.

The second issue is that you are using a `CanvasRenderer()` that does not have GPU accelration. Use the `WebGLRenderer()` instead.

Comment: Thanks your help. I made the changes your mentioned and the sphere seems to be spinning a bit smoother, but its way to tiny now. I tried seeing if i could change some of the other settings, to zoom in the camera or something, but nothing worked

Comment: also, i tried editing and changing canvasrenderrer to webglrenderer but it only made the ball turn black. No more colors.... any idea why that might be?

Comment: For the tiny issue you can keep the radius to 200. For the blackness you need to add a light to the scene.

Comment: thanks, its working a lot better now. Still not spinning for me on mobile tho. Also i tried to change its vertical starting angle so that the white is at the center, but instead of spinning the ball, it seems to cut off the bottom of the ball (i left it up on the example link) Which is weird because when i change the horizontal starting angle, it prespins it properly to another color on the horizontal axis. Any idea why its clipping the skin that way?

Comment: that is a totally different subject and you should open a new question.

Comment: sure thing, ill do that, thanks for help, any idea why it might not be working on mobile tho, its just that i already posted that question before, and im not sure stack would appreciate me asking it 3 times... but i still havent been able to figure out an answer, even tho sphere works just fine in the basic threejs example https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/SphereGeometry

Comment: when you `mobile` it is a very broad category. You need to be more specific; apple, android, which browsers on those devices. I would play with the sphere `widthSegments` and `heightSegments` to see how low you would need to go.

Comment: ios safari. the sphere in the link i sent above works just fine on my mobile browser, but the sphere im working on is just frozen in place. It generates correctly, i just cant spin it around with my touchscreen.

Comment: do the other browsers on ios exhibit the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already resolved the problems ?

The bug recurrence on my android mobile with chrome browser app.The version is `64.0.32`
As you said, the sphere texture appears correctly. But sadly, can't rotate it with when I drag it.

So the first idea come to my mind is to find a debug tool. I use a chrome Remote Device (a debug tool) to check the browser console on my chrome app.

You can see the screenshot below:
[image: chrome console]

S3TC compressed textures not supported. As a comparison, I test it with chrome on desktop, the consoles didn't contain the same warnings.

I think is related to phone's GPU compatibility.